# SQL Query to exclude a certain user on a certain day

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I'm trying to write a SQL query which will be used in an SSRS report.
It is to show the number of changes made to a table by a user between two dates.
I have the query working fine except when I try to remove all entries by a certain user on a certain day as these were done to cleanse the data and will skew the values.

The WHERE clause I have tried is as follows:

```
WHERE
(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Hist.Timestamp), 0) >= @FromDate)
AND
(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Hist.Timestamp), 0) < @ToDate)
AND
(Hist.Timestamp <> '2022-04-26' AND Hist.UserId <> 'DOMAIN\John.Smith')
```

But this removes all entries by that user and not just entries by that user on that day.

How can I edit this WHERE clause to to exclude the results which are for both items?

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
...AND NOT (hist.timestamp = '2022-04-26' AND hist.userid = 'DOMAIN\John.Smith')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately this then shows the full dataset for that user including the results on that date.

Comment: The answer shows the logic you have asked for. If this doesn't do what you want, you have further problems (like as example maybe this kind of hardcoded date checking without providing the format of the date is risky). If you need further assistance, please provide sample data and expected outcome.

Comment: Your comment regarding format of the date has given me the answer for my specific set of data as the hist.timestamp is a DATETIME format therefore only entering the date in the WHERE clause was not correct. I have edited it to AND NOT (Hist.Timestamp < '2022-04-27' AND Hist.UserId = 'DOMAIN\John.Smith') which now works.

Comment: Great, that is what I meant by "risky" ;)